# Can't Adjust Inventory Value Using QuickBooks SDK

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

I am using QBFC to make inventory adjustments in QuickBooks. I can make quantity adjustments with out a problem. However trying to make value adjustments results in an error. (Failed on do requests) I've tried changing the purchase cost on the items before making the quantity adjustments but it doesn't have the desired effect because QB calculates the total value using the Average Cost. I've also tried doing and InventoryAjustmentMod but no success with that. Note that I'm using QuickBooks Premier Retail 2013, opened in single user mode. Even the QuickBooks example project fails, which brings up these questions:

1. Is it possible to adjust inventory values using the SDK? (I can do so in the UI without a problem.)
2. Could a setting be preventing me from successfully adjusting the inventory value?

Answer (score 0):

Whew found the answer!

I was trying to do the adjust like this:

```
adj.InventoryAdjustmentLineAddList.GetAt(counter).ORTypeAdjustment.ValueAdjustment.ORValueAdjustment.NewValue.SetValue(NewValue)
```

Instead I needed to create an IValueAdjustment object like this:

```
DIM AdjValue AS QBFC13Lib.IValueAdjustment = adj.InventoryAdjustmentLineAddList.GetAt(counter).ORTypeAdjustment.ValueAdjustment
AdjValue.ORQuantityAdjustment.NewQuantity.SetValue(NewQuantity)
AdjValue.ORValueAdjustment.NewValue.SetValue(NewValue)
```

Note that ValueDifference didn't work I needed to use NewValue.